# Clarification of an atomic value example and its right definition

Tags: xpath

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_nodes.asp) I found the following example of an atomic value: J K. Rowling.

But in the file.xml I saw that the author element, whose value is J K. Rowling, has a parent, its parent should be the book element. Why is "J K. Rowling" an atomic value?

The definition of an atomic value is (from w3schools): Atomic values are nodes with no children or parent. If this definition is not correct, what is the right one?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711740/in-xml-is-an-atomic-node-the-same-thing-as-a-leaf-node

Comment: Information from w3schools is fine as a first tutorial, but details like you are describing in this question are mostly wrong. w3schools is not affiliated with the W3C (the organization that curates standards such as XPath).